# Flutter BoxShadow without affecting the semi-transparent container's color

Tags: flutter

I am trying to convert this effect from CSS to Flutter, but Flutter's Box Shadow seems to always be drawn under the container and blends with the Container's color if it is semi-transparent.

CSS (desired result):

[image: CSS boxShadowResult]

```
.rectangle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 114px;
  top: 12px;
  background-color: rgba(225, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 50px 50px black;
}
```

Flutter:

[image: CSS Flutter's BoxShadow Result]

```
Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.2),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    blurRadius: 50,
                    offset: Offset(0, 50),
                    blurStyle: BlurStyle.normal)
              ]),
        ),
```

The code are pretty similar, but the results have a major difference.

Comment: you said shadowbox is always drawn under container but your image says the opposite? did you maybe swap css and flutter images?

Comment: In CSS, Shadow is clipped to show only on the outside, but in Flutter, Shadow is not clipped at all

Comment: don't use opacity on `BoxDedecoratio.color` use it on `BoxShadow.color` if you want. I tried it and seems like what you need.

Comment: I need my `Container` to be semi-transparent, as I want users to get a glimpse of what's under it. Like looking through a glass.

Comment: This container image in CSS doesn't have opacity in color, probably the transpiler removes this opacity because it doesn't make sense to make it transparent with a shadow at the bottom, it happens just like in the flutter image, you have a shadow leaking into the container.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a trick solution.

At first, draw Container has same with background color(white) with shadow.
And draw your Container on the this container.

[image]

```
Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 300,
                height: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        blurRadius: 50,
                        offset: Offset(0, 50),
                        blurStyle: BlurStyle.normal)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 300,
                height: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.2),
                 
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using an opaque container in the same position as the semi-transparent one will eliminate the benefits of the semi-transparent, as it wont be able to blend in with the background.